# Access Jquery DOM Element

Tags: jquery, dom, element

I'm using the jquery validation plugin. Trying to access the DOM Element for the form submithandler.

This is the code. You can see I'm trying to access the element id but I can't because it is a DOM object.

```
$("#accept_form").validate({
   rules: {           
   },
   messages: { 
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) { 
   var id = $("#myitid").attr("value");
   alert(id);

}
});
```

How do I get that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Maybe kind of dumb that I missed this but it was as simple as using the val instead of the attr tag.

```
var id =  $('#myitid').val();
```

By using that I was able to get the id I needed from the DOM Element sent by the submithandler. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you're missing `$` for your selector here:

```
var id = $("#myitid").attr("value");
// ----- ^ here ---------
```

Comment: Doesn't work even with that. I have that in my code but I accidentally deleted it when I was posting.

Comment: Does your element `#myitid` has `value` attribute?

Comment: Yes it does. It's not the HTML. I don't have something right in the jquery.